# How to lookup each and every domain that ends with .JOBS TLD?

Tags: dns

I want to find domains from the internet that ends with .JOBS. Should I use Brute Force? If yes so how? Or some other database is available already to query from?

I need your help friends.

Umair

Comment: Just out of curiosity; what would you plan to do with that list?

Comment: By "Brute Force", do you mean that you would set up some kind of loop and have it try to open an http connection to every possible combination of letters, numbers and symbols with ".JOBS" appended?  That seems like it could (literally) take forever.

Maybe provide us more info into what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: @Guy: Well, not _literally_ forever :)  If you assume a maximum of 63 characters for the label just before the TLD (which I think is the maximum), and assume only letters and numbers, and use say a 30-second timeout for the site to respond... 1.06016190875708990784739487879e+92 years.  Cutting down on the timeout can reduce that by an order of magnitude.  But, just one order of magnitude.

Comment: @David: That assumes a static list :)

Comment: I want you guys to write a PHP code to get them from Google by "site:.jobs" keyword please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's unlikely that you'll be able to just download a list.  But, since there are restrictions on the .jobs TLD (i.e. you have to agree to their terms, and it's fairly strictly policed), you can cut down on your "brute force" approach.  For example, you could start by getting a list of the S&P 500 companies' sites and trying them.  That is, instead of [www.walgreens.com](http://www.walgreens.com), try [www.walgreens.jobs](http://www.walgreens.jobs).  You could go far by getting lists of big companies and trying www.[CompanyName].jobs.

You could do a lot better with a focused Web crawler that you seed with the urls of business sites, and have it look for ".jobs" links.  But doing such a thing is a fairly involved bit of work.

See http://www.goto.jobs/policies.asp for information about restrictions on the .jobs domain.

Answer (score 2):

[Crawl Google for "site:.jobs".](http://www.google.com/search?q=site%3A.jobs)

Comment: Thanks for your reply guys.

Well I need to search for all the registered domains that ends with .JOBS. This is a high priority to search all registered domains that are working without skipping a single domain.

By Brute I was assuming that I should start a loop of minimum 3 characters (or minimum characters enforced by .JOBS TLD, do you know that?) till infinity but as you guys said I can stop it to 63 characters, that's good.

Can someone write a PHP code/Pseudo-code to demonstrate how I can generate names within 3 of 63 range or N of 63 range?

It would be really appreciated.

Umair

Comment: hey can you give me some PHP code to crawl using GOOGLE? I write one but that didn't work well and always give Parsing Error.

Answer (score 2):

Bribe someone with access to a root name server or the Authoritative name server for .jobs.

Answer (score 2):

All recognised gTLDs (but not the ccTLDs) are required to make their zone file available, albeit with many terms and conditions attached.

Answer (score 0):

To caveat on Jim's answer, this [link](http://www.goto.jobs/policies.asp) to the .jobs website lists in a flash animation on the left hand side, all the websites that are using the .jobs domain now. You could probably sit there and type it all into a list or pay a friend/niece/nephew to copy them down for you.

Comment: I saw that scrolling list.  Are you sure that's all of the sites that are using .jobs?

Comment: @Jim: I don't know but it is about a definitive list as any seeing as you must be vetted in order to use the site TLD.